# How can I retrieve the value of a field in a flagging?

Tags: flags

I have a global flag, `spam`, that has a textfield, `reason`, attached to it.

According to the [Flag API documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1748148), I know I can check whether a user is flagged like this:

```
$spam && $spam->is_flagged($account->uid)
```

However, in this case, I want to retrieve the flagging, and then check the value of a field in that flagging.  I didn't see any directions for doing so in the documentation, so I'm at a loss about how best to proceed.

Comment: What type of var is `$spam`? Hopefully it's `flag_entity` but maybe it's `flag_flag`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Flag API

[flagging_load](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!flag!flag.module/function/flagging_load/7)

> Loads a flagging entity. Parameters
>
> $flagging_id: The 'flagging_id' database serial column.
>
> $reset: Whether to reset the DrupalDefaultEntityController cache.
>   Return value
>
> The entity object, or FALSE if it can't be found

Therefore something like this might work:

```
$flaggings = flag_get_user_flags('node', $node->nid);
if (isset($flaggings['spam'])) {
    $flagging = flagging_load($flaggings['spam']->flagging_id);
}
```

You will then find your field in:

```
$flagging->field_reason
```